# How to found if an event already bound with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was using a syntax like

```
$("body").on("click", ".className", function(){
    // some code
});
```

it was working fine, then I reloaded the entire page with ajax (no browser refresh), then the event started firing twice, another refresh - fired thrice and so on.

then I converted the code to

```
$("body").off("click", ".className").on("click", ".className", function(){
    // some code
});
```

it's fixed the issue to some extent. Even after this I am getting multiple firing in some scenarios. Is there a way to find out if there are existing 'on' events bound more than once on the element, remove them all and bind it for one time only?

Not sure if this is a valid question, or I was able to explain it clearly.

Comment: Do you call that function everytime you load the page with ajax?

Comment: Set an `init` variable to true after the first bindings, and check that variable before binding again.

Comment: You'd have better to not wrap your binding code inside any handler/callback then

Comment: Is this JavaScript executing **inside** of the AJAX content? Or once on your page?

Answer (score 2):

If you are delegating everytime you are loading the page with ajax it will bind again and again on body's children .classname thus causing the unwanted effect

```
$(function () {
    $("body").on("click", ".className", function () {
        // some code
    });

    function loadpage() {
        //ajax call
    }
    loadpage();
});
```

Try to put your event delegation outside loadpage function

Comment: Actually I am making the call inside the click callback function and rendering the page.

Comment: @Souviiik so why are you binding it inside click handler???

Comment: What do you suggest? Code is like

    $("body").off("click", ".className").on("click", ".className", function(){
        $.ajax().done(function(data){ // render page with data });
    });